# Not able to see repository in Azure Container Registry.

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

[image]

I'm trying to DevOps on VSTS with dockerization. Setup is working fine from E2E, only problem is I don't see images published to the Azure Container registry(ACR).
Pls. throw some light on this.
Have created a basic SKU ACR  in East US region.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the following and see if it works?
1. Log out Azure Portal and then log back in. 
2. Change to another machine.
3. Use docker client to log in and pull image.

Also did you somehow change the DNS manually on the machine for your registry?

If it still not working, could you please send the following information to acr-feedback@microsoft.com?
1. your registry name
2. please ping your registry url (ping yourregistry.azurecr.io), and copy/paste the result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a similar issue and the options mentioned aren't working in the UI. But the below command in the Azure CLI is giving me the correct results:

```
az acr repository list --name registryname --output table
```